# Error message: Not unique table/alias MySQL

Tags: mysql, table-alias

I am trying to insert sap_id from butikkdata2 into energy_stage_ext2 using a left join on male_id.

This is my query:

```
insert into energi_stage_ext2  ( maale_id, maale_date, kwh_t, lev_id, 
                                 konsept, name, slag, sap_id )
select butikkdata2.sap_id 
  from butikkdata2 left join butikkdata2
          ON energi_stage_ext2.maale_id=butikkdata2.maale_id;
```

But I get the error message: Not unique table/alias.

Any ideas?

Comment: `from butikkdata2 left join butikkdata2`.  How does it know which one you want?  You need to give one (or both) an alias.

Comment: @RocketHazmat You should post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `from butikkdata2 left join butikkdata2`, and then you're asking `energi_stage_ext2.maale_id=butikkdata2.maale_id`.

How does it know which `butikkdata2` you want?  The one in FROM or the one in JOIN?

You need to give one (or both) an alias.

```
INSERT INTO energi_stage_ext2 (maale_id, maale_date, kwh_t, lev_id, konsept, name, slag, sap_id)
SELECT bu1.sap_id 
FROM butikkdata2 AS bu1
LEFT JOIN butikkdata2 AS bu2 ON energi_stage_ext2.maale_id=bu2.maale_id;
```

Now, I'm named them `bu1` and `bu2`.  Make sure that in your query you are refering the right field from the right table.

P.S. I'm not sure if you can actually do `energi_stage_ext2.maale_id=bu2.maale_id`.  You aren't JOINing `energi_stage_ext2` in your query.  You might need to JOIN that first, I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: You are correct in assuming I am not able to do -´energi_stage_ext2.maale_id=bu2.maale_id´. That gives me unknown column in on clause. Hmm. I need to approach this in another way. Thanks.

Comment: @user2718837: My suggestion is to just focus on the `SELECT` for now.  Get that working, then add the `INSERT INTO`.  P.S. The `SELECT` should return the same number of fields as you are `INSERT`ing.